# The inverse of the function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How to find the inverse of \begin{equation} 
f(x)=\frac{sinx}{cos^{2}x}
\end{equation}

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Hint: could you invert $g(t)=\dfrac t{1-t^2}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not one-to-one, so it does not have an inverse unless you restrict it to an appropriate interval.
In this case $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ could be one such interval.
$f(x) = y$ is equivalent to $g(\sin(x)) = y$, where $g(s) = s/(1-s^2)$.  So 
$$\sin(x) = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}$$
If $y$ is real, $\sqrt{1+4y^2} > |2y|$, so only the $+$ term has a chance to give you a result in $[-1,1]$.  Thus the inverse to the restriction of your function to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ is
$$ f^{-1}(y) = \arcsin \left( \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}\right) $$
defined on all of $\mathbb R$.

EDIT: As fleablood pointed out, the formula is undefined for $y=0$.  However, it's easy to see that $f^{-1}(0) = 0$.

Comment: What if $y = 0$?

Comment: Good point.  I edited.